# Apache Config proxy SSL

Tags: apache, ssl, proxy, port

I'm having trouble with Apache Proxy SSL, In which I need to forward and use a different port other than 443 with SSL but It's not working without SSL I can do the proxy just fine, I need your help.

I've tried to add the following: See my code below:

```
<VirtualHost *:4040>

     ServerName example.com

     AllowCONNECT 4040
     SSLEngine On
     SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/certs/www_mydomain.crt
     SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/certs/www_mydomain.key
     SSLCACertificateFile /etc/ssl/certs/ca.crt

     SSLProxyEngine On
     SSLProxyProtocol all -SSLv2 -SSLv3
     ProxyRequests Off
     SSLProxyVerify require
     SSLProxyVerifyDepth 1
     SSLProxyCACertificateFile /etc/ssl/certs/ca.crt

     ProxyPass "/" "https://192.168.90.6:9696/"
     ProxyPassReverse "/" "https://192.168.90.6:9696/"
</VirtualHost>
```

The backend server was already encrypted in SSL

```
<VirtualHost *:9696>

     ServerName 192.168.90.6:9696

     SSLEngine On
     SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/certs/www_mydomain.crt
     SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/certs/www_mydomain.key
     SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/ssl/certs/ca.crt

</VirtualHost>
```

When I access `https://www.example.com:4040` it should have `https://192.168.90.6:9696` by default but I get an error of

> This site can't provide an insecure connection.

I'm stuck in this, Hope somebody can help me configure the proxy properly.

Did I miss anything or overlooked? I've used all my certs properly and validated by my CA or do I need another format or wrong in the configuration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for viewing my question,

But I've fixed the following with the following changes:

On the Proxy Server:

```
 SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/certs/www_mydomain.crt <---- This should be in pem format

 SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/certs/www_mydomain.pem <---- This should contain your
                                                          concatenated server cert & rootca cert

 SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/certs/www_mydomain.key <---- This remains the same key for your cert
```

Remove the SSLCertificateChainFile or comment it.

Do this too on the backend server that will be serving SSL in your configuration file.

Goodluck Folks! If you're suffering the same and this solves, Very Nice! Have a good day